# Create dummy variables that are dependent on IDs following an ordered sequence

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization, sequence, dummy-variable

Here is my input:

```r
structure(list(date = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 
1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 
1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 
1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
1990, 1991, 1992), member1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2), member2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), active1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), active2 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2), task = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -54L))
```

Here is my desired output:

```r
structure(list(date = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L), member1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    member2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), active1 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), active2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), task = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
    ), dummy1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), dummy2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -54L))
```

***What I want to do:*** **I want to create two dummy variables, defined matehmatically as follows. I give a more verbal description below.**

[image]

A kind of convoluted process. There are several groups of tasks, each task given by its identifier in the variable `task`, and belonging to a group of tasks as detailed in the variable `group`. Essentially, I want to make a dummy variable that is dependent on whether `(member1, member2)` follow the tasks *in order* in a given year.

For example, take `group == 1` for `(member1, member2) == (1, 2)` (the first nine rows in the dput). For these two members, there are 3 tasks (`task == {1, 2, 3}`) in one group (`group == 1`) of tasks. `active1` and `active2` describe whether `member1` and `member2`, respectively, are 'actively' doing the corresponding `task` in `group` in a given `year`. For `task == 1` in `year == 1990`, only `member1` is actively doing the task (`active1 == 1, active2 == 0`), but for the next two years, both members are actively doing the task (`active1 == 1, active2 == 1`), and so on.

For each task in each group, and for each pair of members, and in each year, I want to generate TWO dummy variables:

1.) one dummy variable equal to unity if a.) the task is the "first" task in the group (i.e., the task with the minimum number) and both `member1` and `member2` have `active == 1` OR b.) if both `member1` and `member2` have `active == 1` AND the task directly before it is also actively being performed. For example, for `group == 1` for `member1, member2`, we'd have this dummy variable == 1  for all years for `task == 1`, this dummy variable == 1 for `year == 1991` for `task == 2`, and this dummy variable == 1 for `year == 1991` for `task == 3`. In other years for these latter two tasks, this dummy variable would equal 0.

2.) My second dummy variable that I want to create is essentially the opposite of the first variable. I want it to equal 1 if the task is a.) NOT the first task in the group but both `member1` and `member2` have `active == 1`, AND b.) the task directly before it is NOT actively being performed, with the dummy equalling zero otherwise. So for example, for `group == 1` for `member1, member2`, this dummy variable would == 0 for `task == 1` in all years, would == 0 for `task == 2` in all years, and would == 1 for `task == 3` in 1992; it would equal unity in this latter case because `member1, member2` are actively performing `task == 3` in 1992, but not performing `task == 2` in that year.

**PLEASE NOTE** that the tasks are not ordered `(1,2,3...)` in my actual database. The tasks skip numbers (e.g, `(10.0, 10.07, 11.0...)`) but are still ordered, so a solution would either a.) have to avoid using the `i, i+1` nomenclature or would first have to convert my task variable into an `i, i+1` format.

**THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP IN ADVANCE!**

**UPDATE:** I received help and the accepted answer worked great for the dput---I've edited their code for my actual dataset, which may or may not help future answer-seekers:

```
  df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(lagtask=dplyr::lag(x=task, n = 1, order_by=grouping),
           lagact1=dplyr::lag(x=active1,1, order_by=grouping),
           lagact2=dplyr::lag(x=active2,1, order_by=grouping)) %>% 
    mutate(lagact1 = ifelse(is.na(lagact1), active1, lagact1),
           lagact2 = ifelse(is.na(lagact2), active2, lagact2)) %>%
      mutate(dummy1=ifelse(active1 == 1 & active2 == 1 &
                             # lag1 == lag(x=Sequence, 1) &
                             (lagact1 == 1 &
                             lagact2 ==1),
                           1,0
      )) %>%
    mutate(dummy2=ifelse(active1 == 1 & active2 == 1 &
                           # lag1 == lag(x=task, 1) &
                           (lagact1 != 1 |
                           lagact2 != 1),
                         1,0
    ))
```

Comment: You'll find help sooner if you provide your expected data.frame output.

Comment: I have edited my question to add my desired/expected output!

Comment: I have also added mathematical formulas for the dummy variables that I want to define, if that helps!

Comment: Just FYI, inside calls to `mutate()` you don't need to pipe into another `mutate()` call to operate on the same variable. You can see an update in my answer removing the extra pipe operators. It was easier to see the steps with the separation at first, but is a little more concise without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused because the OP states that `dummy2` should be 0 for `task 1` and `task 2` in all years for `group 1` except it should equal 1 for `task3` in 1992. However, the expected output shows `dummy2` only equal to 1 for `task 2` in 1991.

```
desired_output[1:9,]
```

Following the language of the question and not the values in the `desired_output` object (which was copied from the OP's post), I think the below works.

```
output <- df %>%
  group_by(date, group) %>%
  mutate(dummy1 = ifelse(task == first(task) &
                           active1 == 1 &
                           active2 == 1,
                         1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(dummy1 = ifelse(active1 == 1 &
                           active2 == 1 &
                           lag(active1 == 1,
                               default = 1) &
                           lag(active2 == 1,
                               default = 1),
                         1, dummy1)) %>%
  mutate(dummy2 = ifelse(task != first(task) &
                           active1 == 1 &
                           active2 == 1,
                         1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(lagtask=lag(x=task, n = 1),
         lagact1=lag(x=active1,1),
         lagact2=lag(x=active2,1)) %>% 
  mutate(dummy2=ifelse(dummy2 == 1 &
                         # lag1 == lag(x=task, 1) &
                         lagact1 == 1 &
                         lagact2 ==1,
                       0,dummy2
  )) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::select(!c(lagtask,lagact1,lagact2))
```

UPDATE: More concise code without extra pipes. It was easier to see the steps using the pipes at first.

```
output <- df %>%
  group_by(date, group) %>%
  mutate(dummy1 = ifelse(task == first(task) &
                           active1 == 1 &
                           active2 == 1,
                         1, 0),
         dummy1 = ifelse(active1 == 1 &
                           active2 == 1 &
                           lag(active1 == 1,
                               default = 1) &
                           lag(active2 == 1,
                               default = 1),
                         1, dummy1),
         dummy2 = ifelse(task != first(task) &
                           active1 == 1 &
                           active2 == 1,
                         1, 0),
         lagtask=lag(x=task, n = 1),
         lagact1=lag(x=active1,1),
         lagact2=lag(x=active2,1),
         dummy2=ifelse(dummy2 == 1 &
                         # lag1 == lag(x=task, 1) &
                         lagact1 == 1 &
                         lagact2 ==1,
                       0,dummy2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::select(!c(lagtask,lagact1,lagact2))
```

Comment: I am marking this as correct, although I did a little bit of editing to your code as shown in my edited post (my edits worked for my actual dataset, but results my vary for the OP's dput). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped! I'll have to take a look at your edits.

Answer (score 2):

This returns the 'correct answer' for dummy1, but I'm stumped on dummy2 sorry.

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df <- structure(list(date = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 
                              1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
                              1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 
                              1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 
                              1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
                              1990, 1991, 1992), member1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                             1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                             1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                                             2, 2), member2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                                                                2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
                                                                                3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), active1 = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                      1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                      1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), active2 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2, 2), task = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -54L))

output <- df %>%
  group_by(date, group) %>%
  mutate(dummy1 = ifelse(task == first(task) &
                          active1 == 1 &
                          active2 == 1,
                          1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(dummy1 = ifelse(active1 == 1 &
                            active2 == 1 &
                            lag(active1 == 1,
                                default = 1) &
                            lag(active2 == 1,
                                default = 1),
                          1, dummy1)) %>%
  mutate(dummy2 = ifelse(task != first(task) &
                           active1 == 1 &
                           active2 == 1,
                         1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(dummy2 = ifelse(dummy2 == 1 &
                           all(lag(active1 == 1,
                                   default = 1),
                               lag(active2 == 1,
                                   default = 1)),
                           0, dummy2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  as.data.frame()

desired_output <- structure(list(date = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
                        1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
                        1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
                        1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
                        1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
                        1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
                        1990L, 1991L, 1992L), member1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
               member2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), active1 = c(1L, 
                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                        0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                        1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                        1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), active2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                     0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                     0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                     0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                     0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L), task = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                              3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                              2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
                                                                                                                                                                        ), dummy1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), dummy2 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -54L), class = c("data.frame"))

# all.equal == TRUE except for dummy2
all.equal(output, desired_output)
#> [1] "Component \"dummy2\": Mean relative difference: 1"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is close, but not exactly what I wanted. I've put my desired output in my question, hopefully that helps!

Comment: I have also added mathematical formulas for the dummy variables that I want to define, if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for including more information. I can't figure out the logic to get dummy2, but hopefully one of the R experts on here will provide a solution.